# php explode for paragraph

Tags: php, explode, paragraph

i have big word.

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3

Paragraph 4

Paragraph 5
```

I must be explode for paragraph.
example : $paragraph[0] must be "Paragraph 1"

Comment: "Paragraph" isn't really that big of a word. Care to explain yourself a little better?

Comment: Im not sure we are fully understanding your question.  Please add some more information and hopefully we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

According your example

```
$paragraph = explode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$paragraphs = explode("</p>", $the_original_text);

echo $paragraphs[0]."</p>";
```